# Open p:confirmDialog on clicking of p:commandLink

Tags: java, jsf, dialog, primefaces, commandlink

I am trying to open a PrimeFace ConfirmDialog on clicking of a PrimeFace CommandLink. But when the link is clicked the dialog is opened for a moment but vanishes instantly, I guess the page is being submitted. Here is the code:

```
<p:commandLink value="Delete" onclick="confirmation.show()"  />

<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure, you want to delete ?"  header="Initiating deleting process"  widgetVar="confirmation">  
    <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure"  onclick="confirmation.hide()"  actionListener="#{adminCtrl.deleteUserById}" update="userData" >
        <f:attribute name="delete" value="#{user.userId}" />
    </p:commandButton>  
    <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />   
</p:confirmDialog>
```

How can I make the dialog to stay opened by this way?

In the [PrimeFace ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf) the example deals with CommandButton and that was working but my requirement is to use CommandLink.

Is it possible? Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Your code-snippet works for me .. error may be somewhere else?

Comment: There's likely a JS error. Read browser JS console for clues. By the way, a command link is completely unnecessary in this construct (assuming that you didn't oversimplify the code too much). Just use a normal link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```html
<p:commandLink value="Delete" onclick="confirmation.show();return false;"  />
```

or

```html
<p:commandLink value="Delete" onclick="confirmation.show()" type="button"/>
```

this way you can avoid a submit

Comment: The first one worked in my case.. Thanks @Kerem Baydogan