# primefaces dialog disappears after show up when click commandLink

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have this code :

```
<h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="Créer un compte" onclick="dlg3.show();"/>
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="modalDialoog" widgetVar="dlg3" draggable="false" resizable="false" dynamic="true" header="Inscription">
<center>
<p:panel id="xyzBody">
<h:form id="inscri-f">
        <h:panelGrid id="loginPan" columns="2" bgcolor="White">

         <h:outputText value="Nom d'utilisateur :" />
         <p:inputText id="username" value="#{demandeBean.login}"></p:inputText>

         <h:outputText value="Mot de passe :" />
         <p:password id="pwd" value="#{demandeBean.pwd}"/>

         <h:commandButton value="Envoyer demande" update=":inscri-f:cr" 
                 actionListener="#{demandeBean.envoi_dde}"></h:commandButton>

         <h:commandButton value="Retour" action="page1?faces-redirect=true"></h:commandButton>

          <p:outputPanel id="cr"> 
            <h:outputText rendered="#{demandeBean.saved}" value="#{demandeBean.message}"/>
          </p:outputPanel>
                </h:panelGrid>
       </h:form>
       </p:panel>
       </center>
       </p:dialog>
```

my problem is when I click commandLink "Créer un compte" dialog is shown and it disappears quickly.

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395844/open-pconfirmdialog-on-clicking-of-pcommandlink)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `<h:commandLink>` executes a submit on the form that will be send the data to the server, the server will process the request, the server will generate a response and send it to client, thus getting the *refresh* behavior in browser.

Easy fix (for this scenario), add `return false;` at the end of the `onclick` to stop the `form` submission.

```
<h:commandLink value="Créer un compte" onclick="dlg3.show(); return false;"/>
```

---

As stated in BalusC comment, it would be easier to not have a `<form>` to begin with, so just using a plain `<a>`:

```
<a onclick="dlg3.show();">Créer un compte</a>
```

Comment: Or just use a plain HTML `<a>` element. Then you can also get rid of that whole form.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `<p:commandlink ...oncomplete="dlg3.show();" />` instead of `<h:commandlink onclick =.... />`
It will ensure setting values in backing bean

Comment: That has the same problem. Read the PF manual again, sine there is a solution, something with `type="button"`